# Sharing code between build.gradle from different projects

Tags: gradle

java-project1 
--- build.gradle

java-project2
--- build.gradle

We've 2 different web projects and both use gradle to build artifacts. There's a lot of code that is repeated between these the build.gradle files. Is there a way to achieve this by abstracting out the common code in groovy files and "importing" them in actual projects' build.gradle?

We tried putting the common code under src/main/groovy... but that too will be repeated across these two projects.

We are thinking about creating a 3rd project now where all these common groovy scripts will live and both project1 and project2 can declare a dependency on that project.

Any pointers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The third project should be a custom Gradle plugin. More info here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

You can use `gradle init` to quickly bootstrap the Gradle plugin project: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html

Once you have extracted the common Gradle/build logic, tested, simply [publish the plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) to either an internal/private repository or a public one such as  [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/).

Then simply apply the newly created Gradle plugin to both projects.